# Odoo: psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL: too many connections for role "p_my_oerp_master_11234451"

Tags: python, postgresql, database-connection, psycopg2, odoo-13

Since Today (the 30 of September), using Odoo v13 on Odoo.sh, after logging in my odoo account as "ADMIN" or another odoo user, i got this error every minute and all "Odoo internal Users" get disconnected from their session every couple of minutes:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  too many connections for role "p_my_oerp_master_1123445"
```

**TRACEBACK:**

```
2022-09-30 17:01:32,442 30903 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
2022-09-30 17:01:32,657 30903 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running through socket activation
2022-09-30 17:01:32,666 30903 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed
2022-09-30 17:01:32,667 30903 CRITICAL ? odoo.service.server: Failed to initialize database `my-oerp-master-1123445`. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 1194, in preload_registries
    registry = Registry.new(dbname, update_module=update_module)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 75, in new
    registry.init(db_name)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 144, in init
    with closing(self.cursor()) as cr:
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 563, in cursor
    return self._db.cursor()
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 669, in cursor
    return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 196, in __init__
    self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 552, in _locked
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 620, in borrow
    **connection_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  too many connections for role "p_my_oerp_master_1123445"
2022-09-30 17:01:32,727 30903 INFO ? odoo.http: HTTP Configuring static files
2022-09-30 17:01:32,736 30903 INFO my-oerp-master-1123445 odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed
2022-09-30 17:01:32,737 30903 INFO my-oerp-master-1123445 odoo.http: Generating nondb routing
2022-09-30 17:01:32,755 30903 INFO None odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed
2022-09-30 17:01:32,755 30903 WARNING my-oerp-master-1123445 odoo.service.model: method ir.cron.acquire_job failed during rpc call: FATAL:  too many connections for role "p_my_oerp_master_1123445"
2022-09-30 17:01:32,755 30903 ERROR my-oerp-master-1123445 odoo.http: FATAL:  too many connections for role "p_my_oerp_master_1123445"
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 61, in __new__
    return cls.registries[db_name]
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/tools/func.py", line 69, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: 'my-oerp-master-1123445'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1479, in dispatch
    odoo.registry(db).check_signaling()
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/__init__.py", line 104, in registry
    return modules.registry.Registry(database_name)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 63, in __new__
    return cls.new(db_name)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 75, in new
    registry.init(db_name)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 144, in init
    with closing(self.cursor()) as cr:
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 563, in cursor
    return self._db.cursor()
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 669, in cursor
    return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 196, in __init__
    self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 552, in _locked
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 620, in borrow
    **connection_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  too many connections for role "p_my_oerp_master_1123445"


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 61, in __new__
    return cls.registries[db_name]
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/tools/func.py", line 69, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: 'my-oerp-master-1123445'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 139, in dispatch_rpc
    result = dispatch(method, params)
  File "/usr/local/bin/odoo-rpc", line 26, in dispatch
    return odoo_dispatch(method, [db, odoo.SUPERUSER_ID, None] + list(params))
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 38, in dispatch
    registry = odoo.registry(db).check_signaling()
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/__init__.py", line 104, in registry
    return modules.registry.Registry(database_name)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 63, in __new__
    return cls.new(db_name)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 75, in new
    registry.init(db_name)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 144, in init
    with closing(self.cursor()) as cr:
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 563, in cursor
    return self._db.cursor()
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 669, in cursor
    return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 196, in __init__
    self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 552, in _locked
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 620, in borrow
    **connection_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  too many connections for role "p_my_oerp_master_1123445"
```

My problem seems to be caused by an hanging process. In Odoo.sh > Monitoring tab ... The "Performance analysis" tool enables to start a profiling session of your Odoo workers. For each session, an interactive flamegraph is generated for you to visualize what your Odoo workers are spending time on. One of these profiling session provide this ouput Flamegraph:

[image]

And the output of ps -ax Terminal Command:

```
my_oerp_master_11234451 [production/v13.0]:~$ ps -ax 
PID TTY STAT TIME COMMAND 

1 ? Ss 2:29 ODOO.SH: [my_oerp_master_11234451 / production / 13.0]

106 ? SNsl 0:56 python3 /usr/local/bin/odoo-rpc --database=my_oerp_master_11234451

4807 ? Ssl 8:44 python3 /home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo-bin --database=my_oerp_master_11234451 --logfile=/home/odoo/logs/odoo.log

5899 ? RNs 0:01 /opt/odoo.sh/jupyterlab/bin/python3 /opt/odoo.sh/jupyterlab/bin/odoo-webshell --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8889 -

5903 pts/0 SNs 0:00 /bin/bash -l

8730 ? SNsl 0:53 python3 /usr/local/bin/odoo-rpc --database=my_oerp_master_11234451

10738 ? SNsl 0:56 python3 /usr/local/bin/odoo-rpc --database=my_oerp_master_11234451

11263 ? SNsl 0:56 python3 /usr/local/bin/odoo-rpc --database=my_oerp_master_11234451

11334 pts/3 SNs+ 0:00 /bin/bash 12134 ? SNsl 0:56 python3 /usr/local/bin/odoo-rpc --database=my_oerp_master_11234451

12864 ? SNsl 0:56 python3 /usr/local/bin/odoo-rpc --database=my_oerp_master_11234451

13384 ? SNsl 0:49 python3 /usr/local/bin/odoo-rpc --database=my_oerp_master_11234451

13584 pts/0 RN+ 0:00 ps -ax

16281 ? SNsl 0:48 python3 /usr/local/bin/odoo-rpc --database=my_oerp_master_11234451

17130 ? SNsl 0:51 python3 /usr/local/bin/odoo-rpc --database=my_oerp_master_11234451

17882 ? SNsl 0:51 python3 /usr/local/bin/odoo-rpc --database=my_oerp_master_11234451

20516 ? SNsl 0:09 /opt/odoo.sh/jupyterlab/bin/python3 /opt/odoo.sh/jupyterlab/bin/jupyter-lab --debug --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888

29069 pts/1 SNs 0:00 /bin/bash

29079 pts/1 SN+ 0:02 less +F /home/odoo/logs/odoo.log

29094 pts/2 SNs+ 0:00 /bin/bash

30181 ? SNsl 0:56 python3 /usr/local/bin/odoo-rpc --database=my_oerp_master_11234451

my_oerp_master_11234451 [production/v13.0]:~$
```

Comment: You have to debug the connection leak in your application.

Comment: Shouldn't your first stop be your PaaS provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more investigation, it seems that crons ("Server Actions" in Odoo) having a recurrence set to None in Odoo, but running in fact every couple of secondes, were the original cause for these "Too many connections..." - Error and the Session disconnection every couple of secondes. On the server side, these crons correspond to processes that use **odoo-rpc** library (external API).

This hypothesis is confirmed by comparing the running processes during the issue (which lasts 5 days long) and after the **cron processes** get killed (somehow):

**DURING ISSUE: running processes (px ax)**

```
my_oerp_master_11234451 [production/v13.0]:~$ ps -ax 

PID TTY STAT TIME COMMAND 
1 ? Ss 2:29 ODOO.SH: [my_oerp_master_11234451 / production / 13.0]

106 ? SNsl 0:56 python3 /usr/local/bin/odoo-rpc --database=my_oerp_master_11234451

4807 ? Ssl 8:44 python3 /home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo-bin --database=my_oerp_master_11234451 --logfile=/home/odoo/logs/odoo.log

5899 ? RNs 0:01 /opt/odoo.sh/jupyterlab/bin/python3 /opt/odoo.sh/jupyterlab/bin/odoo-webshell --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8889 -

5903 pts/0 SNs 0:00 /bin/bash -l

8730 ? SNsl 0:53 python3 /usr/local/bin/odoo-rpc --db_maxconn=2  --database=my_oerp_master_11234451

10738 ? SNsl 0:56 python3 /usr/local/bin/odoo-rpc --db_maxconn=2 --database=my_oerp_master_11234451

11263 ? SNsl 0:56 python3 /usr/local/bin/odoo-rpc --db_maxconn=2 --database=my_oerp_master_11234451

11334 pts/3 SNs+ 0:00 /bin/bash 12134 ? SNsl 0:56 python3 /usr/local/bin/odoo-rpc --database=my_oerp_master_11234451

12864 ? SNsl 0:56 python3 /usr/local/bin/odoo-rpc --db_maxconn=2 --database=my_oerp_master_11234451

13384 ? SNsl 0:49 python3 /usr/local/bin/odoo-rpc --db_maxconn=2 --database=my_oerp_master_11234451

13584 pts/0 RN+ 0:00 ps -ax

16281 ? SNsl 0:48 python3 /usr/local/bin/odoo-rpc --db_maxconn=2 --database=my_oerp_master_11234451

17130 ? SNsl 0:51 python3 /usr/local/bin/odoo-rpc --db_maxconn=2 --database=my_oerp_master_11234451

17882 ? SNsl 0:51 python3 /usr/local/bin/odoo-rpc --db_maxconn=2 --database=my_oerp_master_11234451

20516 ? SNsl 0:09 /opt/odoo.sh/jupyterlab/bin/python3 /opt/odoo.sh/jupyterlab/bin/jupyter-lab --debug --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888

29069 pts/1 SNs 0:00 /bin/bash

29079 pts/1 SN+ 0:02 less +F /home/odoo/logs/odoo.log

29094 pts/2 SNs+ 0:00 /bin/bash

30181 ? SNsl 0:56 python3 /usr/local/bin/odoo-rpc --db_maxconn=2 --database=my_oerp_master_11234451

my_oerp_master_11234451 [production/v13.0]:~$
```

**AFTER ISSUE: running processes (px ax)**

```
my_oerp_master_11234451 [production/v13.0]:~$ ps -ax 

PID TTY STAT TIME COMMAND 

1 ? Ss 2:29 ODOO.SH: [my_oerp_master_11234451 / production / 13.0]

8855 ? Ssl 8:44 python3 /home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo-bin --database=my_oerp_master_11234451 --logfile=/home/odoo/logs/odoo.log

10597 pts/0 SNs 0:00 /bin/bash -l

10601 ? SNsl 0:09 /opt/odoo.sh/jupyterlab/bin/python3 /opt/odoo.sh/jupyterlab/bin/jupyter-lab --debug --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888

11023 pts/1 RN+ 0:00 ps ax

23954 pts/2 SNs+ 0:00 /bin/bash
```

This hypothesis is confirmed too by the official Odoo documentation concerning the psycopg2-Error related to "the maximum connections parameter": https://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin/db_maxconn.html

```
db_maxconn – specify the the maximum number of physical connections to posgresql per odoo process, but for all databases
```

To resolve it you need configure following parameters:

In odoo

- db_maxconn
- workers
- max_cron_threads

In posgresql

- max_connections

Those parameters must satisfy following condition:

(1 + workers + max_cron_threads) * db_maxconn < max_connections

For example, if you have following values:

```
workers = 1 (minimal value to make longpolling work)
max_cron_threads = 2 (default)
db_maxconn = 64 (default)
max_connections = 100 (default)
```

then (1 + 1 + 2) * 64 = 256 > 100, i.e. the condition is not satisfied and such deployment may face the error described above.

Ok, but which values are good for specific server and load conditions?

PostgreSQL’s max_connections should be set higher than db_maxconn * number_of_processes. You may need to tweak the kernel sysctl if you need max_connections higher than 1-2k.

For multi-processing mode, each HTTP worker handles a single request at a time, so theoretically db_maxconn=2 could work (some requests need 2 cursors, hence 2 db connections). However for multi-tenant this is not optimal because each request will need to reopen a new connection to a different db - setting it a bit higher is better. With lots of workers, 32 is a good trade-off, as 64 could make you reach kernel limits. Also keep in mind that the limit applies to the longpolling worker too, and you don’t want to delay chat messages too much because of a full connection pool, so don’t set it too low no matter what. Keeping the value in the 32-64 range usually seems a good choice.

For multi-thread mode, since there is only 1 process, this is the size of the global connection pool. To prevent errors, it should be set between 1x and 2x the expected number of concurrent requests at a time. Can be estimated based on the number of databases and the expected activity. Having a single process handle more than 20 request at a time on a single core (remember that multi-thread depends on the GIL) is unlikely to give good performance, so again, a setting in the 32-64 range will most likely work for a normal load.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error you submitted, it appears to be an SQL command constantly running in the background and as more users log in, the database crashes. This could potentially be due to either a third-party module or a custom code (created through studio).

As you are in PaaS you can check queries that are running by using `pg_activity` in `webshell` and terminate the blocking query or check connections of the specified user in `psql` by using the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   pg_stat_activity
WHERE  usename = 'p_my_oerp_master_1123445';
```

Then cancel the user connections by killing the blocking query with [pg_cancel_backend(pid)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL-TABLE)

Make sure to not make a mistake otherwise you may terminate some important queries.

Comment: @sylvain haha still valid as you customized the configuration file!

Comment: @sylvain db_maxconn = 2 is not set in default configuration

Comment: @sylvain On ubuntu 18.04, pg_activity uses python2 which usage has been removed from Odoo SH. The solution is to use 20.04 to get access to pg_activity

Comment: @sylvain the flamegraph cotains data that only helps define the bottleneck in Odoo, basically a stack trace (you cannot get the exact process that is causing the problem). so you just need to follow traces to get to the last one that is triggering the issue and it should be highlighted in red

Comment: @sylvain it seems to be something that has to do with a certain view

Comment: @sylvain `render (website/models/ir_ui_view.py:347`